# Can I use GridSearchCV to swap transformers in my pipeline?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am working on a regression problem and would like to evaluate the effect of using different standardisation methods (`StandardScaler`, `RobustScaler`, `Normalizer`, ...).
Later on, I would also like to evaluate different methods for dealing with missing data (`SimpleImputer`, `IterativeImputer`).

Here is my current setup.

```
# Create some dummy data
X = pd.DataFrame({
    'x1': np.random.rand(1000)*123 - 83,
    'x2': np.random.rand(1000)*23 + 34
})
y = X['x1'] * X['x2'] + 5 * X['x2'] - 9012 + np.random.rand(1000) * 1000

# Set up three pipelines with different scalers
pipe1 = Pipeline([
    ('scale', StandardScaler()),
    ('svr', svm.SVR())
])
pipe2 = Pipeline([
    ('scale', RobustScaler()),
    ('svr', svm.SVR())
])
pipe3 = Pipeline([
    ('scale', Normalizer()),
    ('svr', svm.SVR())
])

# SVR parameters for each pipeline
param_grid = [
  {'svr__C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'svr__kernel': ['linear']},
  {'svr__C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'svr__gamma': [0.001, 0.0001], 'svr__kernel': ['rbf']},
]

# Apply GridSearchCV and report.

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe1, param_grid, cv=5, n_jobs=-1).fit(X, y)
print('Best score ({:.2f}) was reached with params {}'.format(grid_search.best_score_, grid_search.best_params_))

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe2, param_grid, cv=5, n_jobs=-1).fit(X, y)
print('Best score ({:.2f}) was reached with params {}'.format(grid_search.best_score_, grid_search.best_params_))

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe3, param_grid, cv=5, n_jobs=-1).fit(X, y)
print('Best score ({:.2f}) was reached with params {}'.format(grid_search.best_score_, grid_search.best_params_))
```

What bothers me is that I have to define a separate pipeline for each scaler. So my question: Is there a way to include different transformers (such as `StandardScaler`, `Normalizer`, ...) in my grid search?

Ideally, I want my code to look something like this:

```
pipe = Pipeline(
    # ???
)

param_grid = [
  {'normalization_method':[StandardScaler, RobustScaler, Normalizer], 'svr__C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'svr__kernel': ['linear']},
  {'normalization_method':[StandardScaler, RobustScaler, Normalizer], 'svr__C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'svr__gamma': [0.001, 0.0001], 'svr__kernel': ['rbf']},
]

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, cv=5, n_jobs=-1).fit(X, y)
print('Best score ({:.2f}) was reached with params {}'.format(grid_search.best_score_, grid_search.best_params_))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a convoluted answer, but it does the job well. Here is the set-up:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer, StandardScaler, RobustScaler, Normalizer
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, random_state = 42)
```

The way I would do it, I would create my custom-made scaler that takes **a scikit-learn scaler** as a parameter.

```
class Scaler(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, scaler = StandardScaler()):
        self.scaler = scaler

    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self.scaler.fit(x)

    def transform(self, x):
        return self.scaler.transform(x)
```

As you can see, all it does is replicating the methods of a regular `scikit-learn` scaler. The only difference is the way it gets initialized. By default, I set `scaler = StandardScaler()` for convenience.

You can then do:

```
scaler = Scaler(StandardScaler())
scaler.fit(X_train)
scaler.transform(X_train)[0:5]

>>> array([[-1.01827123,  1.2864604 , -1.39338902, -1.3621769 ],
   [-0.7730102 ,  2.43545215, -1.33550342, -1.49647603],
   [-0.03722712, -0.78172474,  0.74837808,  0.92090833],
   [ 0.20803391,  0.8268637 ,  0.4010645 ,  0.51801093],
   [ 1.06644751,  0.13746866,  0.51683569,  0.3837118 ]])
```

This will be equivalent to

```
sl_scaler = StandardScaler()
sl_scaler.fit(X_train)
sl_scaler.transform(X_train)[0:5]

>>> array([[-1.01827123,  1.2864604 , -1.39338902, -1.3621769 ],
   [-0.7730102 ,  2.43545215, -1.33550342, -1.49647603],
   [-0.03722712, -0.78172474,  0.74837808,  0.92090833],
   [ 0.20803391,  0.8268637 ,  0.4010645 ,  0.51801093],
   [ 1.06644751,  0.13746866,  0.51683569,  0.3837118 ]])
```

Now the part that will be interesting for you is that you can use it in a pipeline:

```
pipe = Pipeline([
     ('scaler', Scaler()),
     ('lr', LogisticRegression())
     ])

pipe.fit(X_train,y_train)
pipe.score(X_test,y_test)
>>> 0.9473684210526315
```

And eventually also in a GridSearch:

```
param_grid = [
  {'scaler__scaler':[StandardScaler(), RobustScaler(), Normalizer()], 'lr__C': 
[1, 10, 100, 1000]},
  {'scaler__scaler':[StandardScaler(), RobustScaler(), Normalizer()], 'lr__C': 
[1, 10, 100, 1000]},
]

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, cv=5, n_jobs=-1).fit(X_train, y_train)

print(grid_search.score(X_test,y_test))
print(grid_search.best_params_)
>>> 0.9736842105263158
>>> {'lr__C': 1000, 'scaler__scaler': Normalizer(copy=True, norm='l2')}
```

This tells you that the best scaler is `Normalizer`.

In case you want to double-check the above, you can still run this:

```
pipe_check = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', Normalizer()),
    ('lr', LogisticRegression())
])

grid_search_check = GridSearchCV(pipe_check, param_grid = {'lr__C': [1, 10, 
100, 1000]}, cv=5, n_jobs=-1).fit(X_train, y_train)
print(grid_search_check.score(X_test,y_test))
print(grid_search_check.best_params_)
>>> 0.9736842105263158
>>> {'lr__C': 1000}
```

This confirms the result we obtained with our custom-made scaler!